# How do i remove the connected gmail account from my main gmail account

Tags: gmail

I Have a main gmail account , Unfortunately i connect another gmail account with my account. Now i like remove this.As i attache an image.

Please help me to do this.

[image: Try to remove second connected gmail account]

Comment: any one can help me please?

Comment: ok i find the answer, it's from the chrome account, just need to delete it from chrome.